# Cannot make valgrind work on OSX mavericks

Tags: c, macos, valgrind, osx-mavericks

I've done a bit of reading:
There is this github issue that talks about this: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/23660
And the bug reported here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=326724

Someone even wrote a patch: http://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=83590

Thing is, I am trying to learn C and relatively new to all this, and I haven't figured out a way to make it work on mavericks. People seem to have been able to at least make *something* work.

Could you give a detailed explanation as to how (either install the patch, or get it working from homebrew maybe, or get the 3.10 version)?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with valgrind? While valgrind is very useful (and I use it myself), there are Mac-specific tools that can achieve some of the same goals.

Comment: I have done some research online, and many people agree it is a great tool to check on memory leaks and other debugging. It is also recommended in the learn C the hard way book I am following

Comment: As of June 15, 2013, homebrew reports valgrind working with OSX 10.9 (I have not tested this).  MacPorts distribution of valgrind does not support OSX 10.9.  Also take a look at [Calvin's valgrind on Mac OSX](http://calvinx.com/2014/05/04/valgrind-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks/)

Answer (score 0):

The current svn version of valgrind (revision 14182) compiles and runs out of the box on Mavericks. The developers seem confident enough that they have removed the warning that is printed on startup, too.